# Add feature extractor to Stanford NER

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

From http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html, to add a new extractor, the last step is:

> Add code to NERFeatureFactory for this feature. First decide which
>   classes (hidden states) are involved in the feature. If only the
>   current class, you add the feature extractor to the featuresC code, if
>   both the current and previous class, then featuresCpC, etc.

Do we only have to add a string to feature collection, such as: `featuresCpCnC.add(getWord(c) + "-PNSEQW");`, and then StanfordNER will parse the string into a real feature? In that case, how do I  specify the specific class/field, e.g., title and author, in the feature string? When I dump features in to text file (using exportFeatures or printFeatures), I only find features with generic class like `June-PSEQW|CpC`, while I want something like `June-DateField-DateField-PSEQW|CpC`, which means `(class[t-1]==DateField)*(class[t]==DateField)*(word[t-1]=="June")`

Comment: It seems that I found the answer. Adding the string is correctly the way to add a new feature extractor. The reason why Stanford NER only have feature with generic class because features with all possible specific classes will be generated then, and the weights for them will be learned using forward backward algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is expected behavior -- are there performance issues that indicate that training is not working as expected?

To elaborate, in the most general case a featurizer `f(x,y)` takes both the input `x` and the output `y`, and constructs a feature vector for that particular pair. However, in many NLP applications, the features only really depend on the input x, and so the featurizer interface we expose is just `f(x)`, and just implicitly join the features with the output class in the backend ([see, e.g., page 10 on "Block Feature Vectors"](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~klein/cs288/sp10/slides/SP10%20cs288%20lecture%205%20--%20maximum%20entropy%20(2PP).pdf)). In this case, it seems reasonable that we'd only print `f(x)`, and not the full `f(x,y)`.

Comment: Thanks. To elaborate more, I believe CRF should calculate weights for all possible f(x,y). Thus, without specifying weights, their print behavior makes sense. However, sometimes, we want to output only f(x,y) with significant weights or f(x,y) with top weight, which will help to discover some useful patterns. The current API seems to not support that.